# Need to make flag value true any how

Tags: java

I need to call this swap file function and do the execution ..but the flag value always remain false.. I need to somehow delete the file and make the flag value true..

```
    void swap_file()
{
   File f = new File("E:\\dream_store\\Employee.txt");
   File t = new File("E:\\dream_store\\temp.txt");
   boolean flag = f.delete();
   t.renameTo(f);
   if (flag)
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File swaped");
   }
   else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not swaped");
}
```

Comment: Step 1) Don't use `File`. Use [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html). Step 2) Work out what your logic is actually doing - currently you assign `flag` to the result of `delete`. You then ignore `flag` and call `renameTo` , ignoring the result. You then output based on the value of `flag`. It's a bit ... odd.

Answer (score 0):

`File.delete()` returns `true` if and only if the file is deleted successfully. So if your return value is `false`, for some reason the delete has not happened.

It's probably worth putting some extra code before the delete (even if temporarily) to verify that your paths are correct. Try (as a minimum):

```
 if(! f.exists()) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("File does not exist: " + f);
 }
```

Look at the docs for `File` for other methods you could test with.

Comment: For `assert` to work, the code needs to be run with `-ea`. Might be worth pointing out...

Comment: Probably simpler for a beginner to use an if statement. Changing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Files` from `java.nio.file` and you could use the:

```
Path sourceFile = Paths.get("path to the source file")
Path targetFile = Paths.get("path to the target file")
Files.move(sourceFile, targetFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

Note that the flag here won't make any sense, since the file will always be moved, unless it doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist then you could check that by calling `Files.exists(...)`.

If you want to print the message in case where the file replacement files, then you could wrap that in the `try ... catch (IOException e)`.